# Adjusting row height according to text in selected column

Tags: excel, vba, row-height

I couldn't find the answer to this and thought the answer may be adaptable to be useful for other things and other people.

In cell G1 is a dropdown list, in columns out to the right are over 300 rows of text, with the header of each column making up what's in the dropdown list (G1). Depending on what is selected in the dropdown list, all other columns are hidden except the column that matches the dropdown list selection.

As there are varying amounts of text (most of it now hidden), with wrapped text and row.autofit turned on, the row heights for the visible column will be much larger than they need to be if one of the hidden columns has a lage amount of text in those particular rows.

I'd like to run a macro that adjusts the row height according to the row heights required for that selected column. Most of it will be single line (15), with around a dozen needing to be made larger. I'd like to set them all the 15 to begin with then find the rows that need a bigger height and adjust the height accordingly.

I understand from other posts that there is no easy solution (I'm using Excel 2007), although I liked the idea of copying the cell content, pasting it to a blank area of the worksheet, using autofit on that row to get the proper row height then applying that row height to where text was copied from.

This is my first post and very much a beginner at this so let me know if I'm doing something wrong in terms of how I pose the question. Below is where I've gotten so far, but I'm getting a type mismatch error on the line beginning If Not..

```
Option Explicit 
Sub AdjustRowHeights()

    ' below code to adjust row height for selected comments

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim r As Integer

    strSearch = "G1"

    ' to set all rows to single row height
    Rows("9:331").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 15

    ' to find the column currently on dislplay (header matching cell G1)
    Set aCell = Rows(5).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    ' cycle through rows checking active comments column for text and adjust row height if necessary
    For r = 9 To 331
    If Not Cells(r, aCell) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(r, aCell).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(350, aCell).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Rows("350:350").EntireRow.AutoFit
        Rows("r:r").Select
        Selection.RowHeight = Rows("350:350").RowHeight
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a type mismatch error because `Cells` expects Long or Integer arguments for the row and column. Try something like:

```
Cells(r, aCell.Column)
```